# Bootstrapping in R. Exit the boot() function before all the replications are evaluated

Tags: r, loops

I use the boot::boot function to perform bootstrapping.
I'm implementing an algorithm to stop the bootstrapping procedure if the statics estimates are stable enough. This should help saving computing time.

But I can't find a way to get out of the boot() function loop.

Here's some dummy code:

```
my.boot <- function(data, R = NULL, auto.stop = T, statistic.fun) { # Wrapper over the usual boot() function

    if (is.null(R)) R = 10000 # Default number of replicas if not set

    bt <- boot(data, function(data, i){

        estimates <- statistic.fun(data, i)

        if(auto.stop == T) {
            if(are.estimates.stable(estimates)) { # Example function that test if the estimates are stable enough
                exit.boot.loop() # The function I'm looking for
            }
        }

        return(estimates)
    })

    return(bt)
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: may we see your code? why not just run to a set number of bootstraps? like `R = 999
> boot.means = numeric(R)
> for (i in 1:R) {
+ boot.sample = sample(cara, 100, replace=T)
+ boot.means[i] = mean(boot.sample)
+ }
> quantile(boot.means, c(.025,.975))`

Comment: I rewrote the question and added some dummy code. I'm using the boot() function because it gives you some additional advantages over self made bootstrap, eg. easy confidence intervals calculation